# What's the order type of the following set?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, ordinal-numbers, constructibility

Fix a positive integer n. Assume $Lan=\{R_0,R_1,...,R_n\}$ be a language of first order logic, where every $R_i$ is a 2-ary relation symbol.

Assume $M$ is an Lan-model, where the underlying set is $ω_1$, and $\alpha R_0 \beta$ iff $\alpha<\beta$, and for $i>0$, $\alpha R_i \beta$ iff $L_\alpha$ is a $\Sigma_i$ elementary submodel of $L_\beta$.

Define $S\subset \omega_1$ be those ordinals $\alpha$ such that there is a finite Lan-model $A$ totally ordered by $R_0$, and $\alpha$ is the least ordinal such that there exists an Lan-monomorphism $A\rightarrow M$ such that the $R_0$-largest element of $A$ is mapped to $\alpha$.

Question: Calculate the order type of $S$.

Comment: This seems to be very much related to the calculation of the order type of Carlson's patterns of resemblance. And the latter question is open since the patterns have been introduced around 20 years.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov The story behind this question is interesting: in 2014 there was a contest to name large numbers where an anonymous contestant submitted a program (patched in 2018) claimed to take longer to terminate than Buchholz's hydra game, but its termination was only conjectural. Over the past couple years various amateur enthusiasts (including OP) have tried proving its termination and determining the size of its output, earlier this year OP made the connection that just by coincidence its algorithm looks similar to a variant of the patterns of resemblance comparison algorithm.

Comment: @C7X Is there some link to this program? It would be curious to take a look.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov [Here's](https://github.com/kyodaisuu/basmat/blob/master/basic/BM4.bas) a link to the 2018 patch of the program (the one most interested in this series of programs agree to be the canonical one), written in a dialect of BASIC. A word of warning: almost everything from the original entry to the 2018 version is conjectural, around 2016 it was found that the original 2014 program doesn't terminate on some inputs: it actually computed a non-well-founded notation whose well-founded part is at most $\Gamma_{\omega+1}$. No evidence of nontermination is yet shown for the 2018 version.

Comment: Additionally, soon after a [PDF](https://naruyoko.github.io/googology/pairSeqProofLaTeX/full.pdf) (not peer-reviewed) was written up of a proof that the 2018 patch of the program terminates on inputs [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],...] of two rows, using an order-preserving injection from this program's "hydra game" to Buchholz's 1984 ordinal notation for $\Pi_1^1-CA_0+BI$. The full program starts with input [[0,0,...,0,0],[1,1,...,1,1]] of length 10, so this is some progress. This PDF uses the notation (a,b)(c,d)... for [[a,b],[c,d],...], and it's in Japanese, I'm not sure if there's a translation.

Comment: For inputs of 1 row, the patterns of resemblance connection is strongest: 1-row input gives the almost exact behavior of Kirby-Paris's hydra game, which in turn matches with the behavior of pure order-1 patterns quite well (Wilken has a talk that brings up these kinds of [forests for pure order-1 patterns](https://youtu.be/G6YGkLNeEq4?t=559), unfortunately a recording of the blackboard during this segment is lost.)

Comment: For ease of use, [here](https://gyafun.jp/ln/basmat.cgi) is an online calculator for finding the nth expansion of a given array (arrays are called *matrices* colloquially, input with rows enclosed in parens as in the PDF), along with some explanation of the program [here](https://kyodaisuu.github.io/basmat/definition.html). Colloquial discussion borrows some terminology from the worm game, such as finding the "good" and "bad" parts of a matrix, as Beklemishev described the "good" and "bad" parts of a worm. (No ethical implications of such a string are implied by this terminology, I hope...)

Comment: @C7X  Thank you! Unfortunately I don't know Japanese. I guess, at some point I'll try to figure out what is the construction here looking at the program code and examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is a $\lambda<\omega_1$ such that $L_\lambda\prec L_{\omega_1}$, this can be obtained by taking the least ordinal not in $\textrm{Hull}^{L_{\omega_1}}(\{\varnothing\})$. According to an (unsourced) statement on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_lemma) the hull is already transitive, so no Mostowski collapse is needed to put it in the form $L_\lambda$. Such $\lambda$ are unbounded in $\omega_1$: for any given $\xi<\omega_1$, by taking $\textrm{Hull}^{L_{\omega_1}}(\xi\cup\{\xi\})$ instead, a $\lambda_\xi>\xi$ can be produced such that $L_{\lambda_\xi}\prec L_{\omega_1}$.

Then, the ordinals $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that there is a $\beta<\alpha$ with $L_\beta\prec L_\alpha$ are unbounded in $\omega_1$. In particular, if $\beta,\alpha<\omega_1$ are such that $L_\beta\prec L_{\omega_1}$, $L_\alpha\prec L_{\omega_1}$, and $\beta<\alpha$, then $L_\beta\prec L_\alpha$. (This may be shown routinely by passing $\phi(\vec a)$ between $L_\beta$, $L_{\omega_1}$, and $L_\alpha$, with $\vec a$ a sequence of parameters from $L_\beta$.) This shows unboundedness since if some $\lambda_\xi$ is chosen for $\beta$, $\lambda_{\lambda_\xi}$ may be chosen for $\alpha$.

Since $\omega_1$ has cofinality $\omega_1$, this unbounded subset of $\omega_1$ must have order type $\omega_1$. Consider the finite $Lan$-model $\{\beta,\alpha\}$, where $\beta,\alpha$ are as in the last paragraph. $\beta R_n\alpha$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb N$, so to get a monomorphism to $M$ there would need to be a two-element subset $\{\gamma,\delta\}$ of $\omega_1$ such that $\gamma R_n\delta$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Taking $\gamma=\lambda_0$ and $\delta=\lambda_{\lambda_0}$, we get that any $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ is such a finite $Lan$-model. As such $\beta$ are unbounded in $\omega_1$, the order type of $S$ is $\omega_1$.